# How to update our trained neural network models with new added features?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

In linear regressions $Y=\boldsymbol{\beta} \boldsymbol{X} + \varepsilon$, at first we had features $\mathbf{X}_1$, and trained our model 
$$
\widehat{Y} = \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 \boldsymbol{X}_1
$$

Later, we came up with some new features $\boldsymbol{X_2}$, and we didn't need to retrain the models to get parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}_1$, we can just train a model $\boldsymbol{\beta}_2 \boldsymbol{X}_2$ to fit residuals $Y - \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 \boldsymbol{X}_1$ using least square estimation:
$$
\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2 \boldsymbol{X}_2 \approx Y - \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 \boldsymbol{X}_1
$$

Combining these two, we have our model:
$$
Y \approx \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_1 \boldsymbol{X}_1 + \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_2 \boldsymbol{X}_2
$$

However, it is more complicated for deep neural networks. Suppose our neural network using features $\boldsymbol{X}_1$ is 
$$
Y = \boldsymbol{W}^{(3)}
g_2\left( \boldsymbol{W}^{(2)} 
g_1\left(
\boldsymbol{W}_1^{(1)} \boldsymbol{X}_1 + \boldsymbol{b}^{(1)}\right) + \boldsymbol{b}^{(2)} 
\right)
+ \boldsymbol{b}^{(3)}
$$
where $g_1, g_2$ are group of activation functions on units of each layer of the neural network.

If we have some new input features $\boldsymbol{X}_2$, could I ask if there is any method that we don't need to retrain the entire model and only use data with features $\boldsymbol{X}_2$ to update the initially trained model? And obtain a new model 
$$
Y = \boldsymbol{W}^{(3)}
g_2\left( \boldsymbol{W}^{(2)} 
g_1\left(
\boldsymbol{W}_1^{(1)} \boldsymbol{X}_1 + \boldsymbol{W}_2^{(1)} \boldsymbol{X}_2 + \boldsymbol{b} \right) + \boldsymbol{b}^{(2)} 
\right)
+ \boldsymbol{b}^{(3)}
$$
that not only can hold the precision of the initially trained model and can capture the contributions of the new features to get higher accuracy? The reason why I ask this is retraining the entire DNN model cost too much time.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: I suspect that adding $W_2 X_2$ in and simply fine-tuning the model for just a few iterations (starting all other weights off at their current value) will result in a performant model. I don't have any proof, but I think it will work because NNs tend to be very pliable to adjustment.

Comment: @shimao Thanks a lot. I agree that the most immediate way to deal with this is to just add $W_2 X_2$ and initial $W_1$ with trained value, I am wondering if there's any other fancy method and any theoretical analysis.